# psuedo inverse of a matrix counter-example

Tags: numerical-methods

I have proved $A^{\dagger}A = I$ for a $m$ by $n$ matrix with $m\geq n$ and $\text{rank}(A) = n$ I am trying to find a counter example which shows that $AA^{\dagger} \not= I$ but to no avail. The only one I have is the 0 matrix, but I guess that's trivial

Comment: Any non orthogonal matrix will do.

Comment: Any such matrix with $m>n$ works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, what you said is not true, since if
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
then $A^\dagger = A^T$, and
$$A^\dagger A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
Let
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
then $A^\dagger = A^T$ and $A^\dagger A = I$, but
$$AA^\dagger = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: sorry I meant to add that $\text{rank}(A) = n$

Comment: In that case, then the second part of my answer with the counterexample still works.

Comment: Works fine, thanks!